# Existe uma maneira de deixar esse código menor?

Tags: python, python-3.x

sou novo na programação de python (não sei nem os básicos direito) e acabei criando esse código em um exercício:

```
uftop = []
while True:
    top = "Choose your pizza toppings"
    top += "\nWrite 'quit' to exit:"
    user_top = input(top)
    uftop.append(user_top)
    if user_top == 'quit':
        uftop.remove('quit')
        
    if user_top == 'quit':
        break
if len(uftop) >= 1:
    print(uftop)
```

O objetivo do código seria de você escrever coisas para colocar em uma pizza, e quando você achar que está suficiente é so escrever a palavra quit, desse jeito a lista criada de coisas para colocar na pizza aparecerá na tela. O problema era que quando escrevia 'quit', quit era imprimido na tela mesmo assim, então tive que resolver o problema colocando uma condição em que se quit fosse a palavra, ela não seria adicionada a lista.
Aí surgiu outro problema: A lista era imprimida mesmo vazia. Então coloquei uma condição que se a lista fosse vazia ela não deveria ser imprimida. Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer isso de um jeito mais legivel e curto. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: o segundo if dentro do loop ta sobrando, vc pode fazer o break apos remover o quit no primiero if

Comment: Em vez de usar `remove`, é mais fácil **não inserir** na lista caso digite "quit": https://ideone.com/xNB46n

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, seguinte, primeiro de tudo, eu alterei o nome das variáveis para ficar mais legível o código, e a partir disso, faria as seguintes modificações com as devidas explicações:

1. Colocaria a mensagem padrão fora do loop while para não ficar reescrevendo sem necessidade.
2. Colocar um if para verificar se a palavra é **quit**, se for quit então sai do loop (break). Caso seja diferente de **quit**, ele adiciona em uma lista de pedidos da pizza.
3. No fim, para não printar a lista vazia, ele verifica se há algum item na lista, se tiver, ele mostra o conteúdo da pizza.

Ficar assim:

```
lista_de_ingredientes = []
message = "Choose your pizza toppings \nWrite 'quit' to exit:"
while True:
    novo_ingrediente = input(message)
    if novo_ingrediente == "quit":
        break
    else:
        lista_de_ingredientes.append(novo_ingrediente)

if lista_de_ingredientes:
    print(lista_de_ingredientes)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).